# How to get the URL for Hive Web Interface

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Sorry, it may be a basic question. I tried to google it but couldn't find exact solution

I am trying to find out URL for my Hive web interface. 
Through this I can check the tables present in it. With the help of the web interface URL I can also access the beeline command line interface

I am accessing my company's server for hadoop interface through putty.
I access hdfs web interface using

```
http://ibmlnx01:50070/
```

However when I try the below URLs, it doesn't show any web userinterface

```
 http://ibmlnx01:9999/
 http://ibmlnx01:10000/ 
 http://0.0.0.0:9999/ 
 http://0.0.0.0:10000
```

Below is my hive-default.xml.template
I couldn't copy the whole file. But copied the main code I hope its sufficient

```
<property>
  <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
  <value>lib/hive-hwi-0.12.0.war</value>
  <description>This sets the path to the HWI war file, relative to ${HIVE_HOME}. </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>This is the host address the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
  <value>9999</value>
  <description>This is the port the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
</property>
```

Below is the code for hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
         <value>jdbc:mysql://volgalnx03.ad.infosys.com/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
         <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
             <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
             <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
     </property>
     <property>
             <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
             <value>hiveuser</value>
             <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
            <value>1234</value>
            <description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

I connect the putty terminal through 10.66.82.52 IP address. If this is of any help

Answer (score 0):

[Hue (Hadoop User Experience)](http://gethue.com/) is the web interface for analyzing data with Hadoop (and not just with Hive).

Hue's standard port is `8888`. 
However, that value may be different in your installation.

Look for the `http_port` entry in `/etc/hue/conf/hue.ini` if `8888` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to all this. Can you tell me where exactly to find /etc folder. Thanks

Comment: /etc is the Linux directory where configuration files are stored. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 0):

just appending hwi helped me ;)
http://host:9999/hwi
Make sure u executed below line first.
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hwi

At first I tried to get ui using url http://host:9999/ and it returned 404.

Comment: Please post more than a link. Explain why it's right.

Answer (score -1):

Double check the installation steps in www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_quick_guide.htm.
 Then, make sure you have JDK on your server. Finally, you should run the execution command:
hive --service hwi
In addition, I inserted a link about Gareth's personal experience in the same situation.

https://dzone.com/articles/hadoop-hive-web-interface